# Getting Value of certain dropdown options

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="states" id="states">
    <option value="100">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="107">Texas</option>
    <option value="200">Colorado</option>
    <option value="333">Florida</option>
  </select>
</body>
<script>
$('#states option').each(function() {
    if (this.text === 'Florida'){
    valueOfFlorida = this.value;
    alert(valueOfFlorida);
    }
});
</script>
</html>
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I want to get the value of a certain state. I am looping through all the elements to compare with the state I want to get the value of.

Comment: What is your actual goal? Do you want all the states to be in a variable? Or you just want the one value?

Comment: `$('#states option:contains("Florida")').val()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `filter` to filter out the desired element :

```js
var choice = $('#states option').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() === "Florida";
});

alert(choice.val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="states" id="states">
  <option value="100">Hawaii</option>
  <option value="107">Texas</option>
  <option value="200">Colorado</option>
  <option value="333">Florida</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to find values for multiples option elements and you know them in advance, you can use them to construct an object which will give you the values you need:

```
//the states
const states = ['Texas', 'Florida'];
//construct object (state/id) pairs
const ids = $('#states option')
//get state/value pairs array
.map((i,o) => ({[o.textContent]:o.value})).get()
//get pairs just for the states of interest
.filter(s => states.includes(Object.keys(s)[0]))
//convert array into object
.reduce((acc, cur) => Object.assign(acc,cur), {});
//output corresponding values
console.log( states.map(s => ids[s]) );
```

**DEMO**

```js
const states = ['Texas', 'Florida'];

const ids = $('#states option').map((i,o) => ({[o.textContent]:o.value})).get()
.filter(s => states.includes(Object.keys(s)[0]))
.reduce((acc, cur) => Object.assign(acc,cur), {});

console.log( ids );
console.log( ids['Florida'] );
console.log( states.map(s => ids[s]) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="states" id="states">
    <option value="100">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="107">Texas</option>
    <option value="200">Colorado</option>
    <option value="333">Florida</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

[KnockoutJs](https://knockoutjs.com/index.html) is perfect for this kind of small and concrete requirements, you can define and bind your model with your HTML template and make operations with your model using pure javascript, making your code clear and clean, KnockoutJs is really easy to learn, literally in minutes you can handle relatively complex things like in your case:

JS:

```
var viewModel = function() {
    states = [{
        name: 'Hawaii',
        value: 100
    }, {
        name: 'Texas',
        value: 107
    }, {
        name: 'Colorado',
        value: 200
    }, {
        name: 'Florida',
        value: 333
    }];
    
    selectedState = ko.observable(states[0]);
    
    getValue = function (name) {
        return states.find(s => s.name == name)?.value;
    }
    
    console.log(getValue('Texas'));
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

HTML:

```
<select
    data-bind="options: states, optionsText: 'name', value: selectedState"
    name="states"
    id="states"
>
</select>
<div>
    Using binding:
    <span data-bind="text: selectedState().value"/>
</div>
<div>
    Using function:
    <span data-bind="text: getValue(selectedState().name)"></span>
</div>
```

See how small and clear `getValue` function is and you can even use it in your HTML

[code snipped](https://jsfiddle.net/b2cdosrk/)